# What is the integral of the fractional part of a variable -- related to integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of a variable, i.e. $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Would the integral of $\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}$ from $0$ to $1$ evaluate to $1$? That is

$$
\int_{0}^1 \{x\} -\frac{1}{2} = 1
$$

Am asking this because I want to apply it to an arbitrary integrable function $f(x)$, where I want to derive its integral using the 'long-cut' of integration by parts.

Particularly, does the following hold for any number $b$?

$$
\int_b^{b+1}f(x) =  \Big(\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}\Big)f(x)|^{b+1}_b - \int_b^{b+1} \Big(\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}\Big)f'(x)
$$

i.e. I take the integral of $f(x)$ from $b$ to $b+1$, and set $u=\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}$, $du=1$, and $v=f(x)$, $dv=f'(x)$, instead of the usual substitution of $x$ for $u$....

Comment: Let $g(x) = \{x\} - 1/2$. If $b > 0$ and $f \in C^1$, integration by parts for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral gives
$$\int_b^{b + 1} f'(x) g(x) \, dx =
f(x) g(x) \bigg\rvert_{x = b}^{b + 1} -
\int_b^{b + 1} f(x) \, dg(x) = \\
f(x) g(x) \bigg\rvert_{x = b}^{b + 1} +
f(\lfloor b \rfloor + 1) - \int_b^{b + 1} f(x) \, dx.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x \in [0, 1)$, we have $\{x\} = x$ and so, we have
$$\int_0^1\left(\{x\}-\dfrac12\right)dx = \int_0^1 \left(x-\dfrac12\right)dx = 0.$$
(The value at $1$ does not matter.)

---

In fact, the function $\{x\}-\dfrac12$ is a periodic function with period $1$ such that the integral over a full period is $0$. So you have
$$\int_b^{b+1}\left(\{x\}-\dfrac12\right)dx = 0$$
for *any* $b \in \Bbb R$. (Not just $b \in \Bbb Z$.)

---

I'm not quite sure what you are doing in the later part with by-parts. However, I'll point this out-

> There exists no $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $F'(x) = \{x\} - \dfrac12$.

This is because $\{x\} - \dfrac12$ does not satisfy the intermediate value property and so, by [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis)), it cannot have an anti-derivative.